# What is the difference between a "Kafka Spout" and a "kafka Consumer"?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

both "Kafka Spout" and "Kafka Consumer" do retrieve data from the Kafka Brokers, the spout so far i know is for communicating with Storm, and the Consumer is with whatever else.

-but still, what is the difference technically?

-or what would be the difference between If i pulled out the data using a Consumer then receive it using a "Storm Spout" and between if i just used a "Kafka Spout" then add it to my Storm Topology Builder's setSpout(); function

-and when to use Consumer, or a Kafka Spout

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A/the "Kafka Spout" is a Storm-specific adapter to read data from Kafka into a Storm topology.  Behind the scenes, the Kafka spout actually uses Kafka's built-in "Kafka consumer" client.

Technically, the difference is that the Kafka spout is a kind of a Storm-aware "wrapper" on top of Kafka's consumer client.

In Storm, you should typically always use the included Kafka spout (see https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/master/external/storm-kafka or, for a spout implementation that uses Kafka's so-called "new" consumer client, https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/master/external/storm-kafka-client).  It would be a very rare case to implement your own -- perhaps the most likely case would be if there is a bug in the existing Kafka spout that you need to work around until the Storm project fixes the bug upstream.

Comment: thank you so much! it's clear now,
but I got 2 more little questions, 
(1)-"should" the KafkaSpout class be extending a basic/rich-Spout? 
(2)-as KafkaSpouts are a Storm-aware wrappers, is it a replacement for a "storm spout" receiving the same data from a "kafka consumer" ? or the "storm spout" should exist anyway?
i mean : that (producer->broker->kafkaSpout->bolts->buildTopology)
or that (producer->broker->kafkaSpout->stormSpout->bolts->buildTopology)

Comment: FWIW, both Kafka spouts that are included in Apache Storm extend `BaseRichSpout`.

Also, a/the Kafka spout is, by definition, a Storm spout.  So the flow is (producer->broker->kafkaSpout->bolts->...).  I'd recommend (re-)reading the Storm documentation.